# How to change Authentication in sharepoint server 2010?

Tags: authentication

how to change Authentication in sharepoint server 2010? By default it takes windows authentication.

After creating website it is possible to change authentication name in website if it possible how it so?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read what Microsoft has discussed in glorious detail about all Authentication Mechanisms supported by SharePoint 2010:-

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx

Additionally, if you are planning for creating a topology with various authentication mechanism follow this deployment reference :- 
 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24079
The alternative to NT authentication is claims based authentication and read here how to implement the same :- 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806886.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806885.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Prasanth,

Authentication is set on the web application level, not on the web site level. To change it, and you can use multiple types of providers, you need access to Central Administration. You also need to understand how to configure the authentication provider you want to use.

The following TechNet article is a great place to start:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx

USPJA (I'm a partner) also has a course on planning and implementing security:
http://www.uspja.com/courses/user-management-and-security-in-sharepoint-2010/

.b